# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined when using react-bootstrap splitdown

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I added a split button dropdown to my page using the example from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns) to test it out.

My code..

```
<SplitButton bsStyle={"primary"} title={"test"} key={1} id={`this-is-a-test`}>
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
</SplitButton>
```

When clicking the split button dropdown, the console shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined

The error points to code in the react-bootstrap.js file.

```
exports.default = function (componentOrElement) {
    return (0, _ownerDocument2.default)(_reactDom2.default.findDOMNode(componentOrElement));
};
```

I've looked at other answers suggesting to upgrade React and React-dom, but i think my versions are ok (Both are 15.3.0).

Edit:

It works in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Zuperman24/pen/ALqXbO) I created importing the same files. Issue must be with my implementation..

Comment: did you import react bootstrap in your file?

Comment: Yes I did. I've been using other react-bootstrap components just fine.

Comment: maybe react bootstrap has a dependency that is older than 0.13? try npm ls and npm outdated to see what you get

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything is up to date with no dependencies missing.

Comment: Try importing ReactDOM from 'react-dom' before importing react bootstrap

Comment: @Anuj Thank you so much. I assumed that I had the import order correct that i didn't even verify. That fixed my issue! I wish I could give you points for answering this correctly.

Comment: @Zee glad to hear it worked! I posted the comment as an answer too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your import order is correct!

Place `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` before you import React Bootstrap